# Is it possible to restrict Alexa or an AVS device to a custom skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, avs

Is it possible to restrict and AVS device (a device running Alexa) to a single skill? So if I built an AI skill and have it running on a device, is it possible to keep the experience inside the custom skill so I don't have to keep saying Alexa, open

Answer (score 1):

One trick you can do with AVS is to prepend every single request with a sound clip equivalent to: "ask  to ..." It's definitely a hack, but I was able to use it with some success.

See my write-up here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/adding-context-alexa-will-blaschko-ma

The relevant parts (in case the link goes away).

> Regular voice commands don't carry my extra information about the
> user, but I wanted to find a way to tack on metadata to the voice
> commands, and so I did just that--glued it right onto the end of the
> command and updated my intents to know what the new structure would
> be.
>
> ...
>
> In addition to facial recognition, voice recognition could help
> identify users, but let's not stop there. Any amount of context can be
> added to a request based on available local data.
>
> “Find frozen yogurt nearby" could silently become “Alexa open Yelp and
> find frozen yogurt near 1st and Pine, Seattle” using some built in
> geolocation in the device (phone, in this case).

I also use something similar in my open source Android Alexa library to send prerecorded commands: https://github.com/willblaschko/AlexaAndroid

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for AWS Lex which allows you to write Alexa like skills without the rest of Alexa feature set.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/what-is.html